# Problem removing duplicates from an ArrayList using public static void removeDuplicate(ArrayList<Integer> list)

Tags: java

I know it is better ways to remove duplicates from a list but my teacher for some reason wants us to use this certain method.

My code works to an extent. For example if I enter "34 2 12 5 2 2 34 12 34 2" as my ten numbers the output will be, "The distinct integers are: 34 2 12 5 2". For some reason 2 comes up twice and I can't figure out why.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RemoveDuplicate {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    System.out.print("Enter ten numbers: ");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        list.add(input.nextInt());
    }

    input.close();

    removeDuplicate(list);

    System.out.print("The distinct integers are: ");
    for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++){
        System.out.print(list.get(i)+" ");
    }
}

public static void removeDuplicate(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    for(int i=0; i<list.size()-1;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<list.size();j++){
            if(list.get(j) == list.get(i)) {
                list.remove(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please avoid posting homework questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Review `j<list.size();j++` and `list.remove(j)`, which skip over the second `2` entry when remove shortens the list.

Comment: I see what you are saying. What would be the way to fix this?

Comment: One standard way is to iterate from the back of the list so when you remove an element from an index, only elements that you are done considering will be shifted.